# Creating transparent overlay for camera in OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create an overlay for a camera feed, and I want the overlay to be blurred, and about 50% transparent. One way of solving this is to copy each frame from the camera, draw onto it, and merge them together using addWeighted. This doesn't work for me because the blur effect takes up so much resources the output fps drops to 10.

Another solution I thought up is to create the overlay once (It's static after all, why recreate it every frame?) and merge it with the camera feed. However the resulting video gets noticeably darker when doing this, seemingly because the overlay mat refuses to be transparent.

```
(*cap) >> frameOriginal;

orientationBackground = cv::Mat(frameOriginal.rows, frameOriginal.cols,
    frameOriginal.type(), cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));
cv::Mat headingBackground;
orientationBackground.copyTo(headingBackground);

cv::Point layerpt1(1800, 675);
cv::Point layerpt2(1850, 395);
cv::rectangle(orientationBackground, layerpt1, layerpt2,
    cv::Scalar(255,80,80), CV_FILLED, CV_AA);

cv::blur(orientationBackground, orientationBackground, cv::Size(7,30));

double alpha = 0.5;
addWeighted(orientationBackground, alpha, frameOriginal, 1-alpha, 0, frameOriginal);
```

The before(left) and after(right) adding the overlay:[image: overlay problem]

I'm using OpenCV 3.10 on windows x64 btw

Comment: just create a `mask` that is 0 where no overlay is and 255 where the overlay is. Then do the following: for each pixel: `if(mask(pixel) == 255) result(pixel) = alpha*background(pixel) + (1-alpha)*image(pixel) else result(pixel) = image(pixel);` If you dont want to iterate manually over all pixel you can use the (maybe slower): `cv::Mat hardBackground = image.clone(); background.copyTo(hardBackground, mask); cv::addWeighted(hardBackground, alpha, image, 1-alpha, 0, result);`

Comment: wouldn't writing that as answer be better? :p

Comment: no time and no possibility to test it =) I hope he'll write the answer himself if he is able to implement it this way. If there are problems I'll write a detailed answer when I find the time.

Comment: I'll try it out. I wont have time this weekend (I should probably have waited with opening this question but oh well), but I'll get right on it on monday :)

Comment: @Micka This doesn't work. The overlay sticks out like a sore thumb in the picture instead of blurring into the background, because the "blurred" part is still much much darker than it should be:

http://oi63.tinypic.com/x514x2.jpg

Comment: ah, I missed the blurring part completely. Can you explain the desired blur-behaviour better? Do you want the marked area to fade? At the moment it is just semi-transparent.

Comment: @Micka If possible, I would like the edges to fade into the background (or into transparency if that's possible) so it doesn't get those incredibly sharp (read: ugly) edges. I'm planning on writing on top of it later, so the text is visible no matter where I point the camera. 

I tried copying the background (camera feed) into a separate Mat, drawing a rectangle, blurring it, and then merging them together with addWeighted. This actually worked, but the "blur" effect takes so much resources the frame rate drops down to 10 fps. So I'm looking into other, less taxing, options.

Comment: is the region fixed at some position? Easiest will be a blending mask, similar to the approach of my previous comments. Unfortunately I don't have time to code it today...

Comment: Yes, the region is fixed. I haven't heard about blending mask before, but that does sound exactly like what I need. I'll look into it :) Thanks!

Comment: @Micka I still have not found a solution to this. I can not find a way using mask that will give the edges a smoother/blurred look.

Comment: is it ok to assume that the overlay is rectangular and fading is performed in each direction? Or can you define what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Micka That is exactly what I want. The square in the picture in OP is how I want it (Just without the black background around it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");

    // define your overlay position
    cv::Rect overlay = cv::Rect(400, 100, 50, 300);

    float maxFadeRange = 20;

    // precompute fading mask:
    cv::Size size = input.size();
    cv::Mat maskTmp = cv::Mat(size, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));

    // draw black area where overlay is placed, because distance transform will assume 0 = distance 0
    cv::rectangle(maskTmp, overlay, 0, -1);

    cv::Mat distances;
    cv::distanceTransform(maskTmp, distances, CV_DIST_L1, CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);

    cv::Mat blendingMask = cv::Mat(size, CV_8UC1);

    // create blending mask from 
    for (int j = 0; j < blendingMask.rows; ++j)
    for (int i = 0; i < blendingMask.cols; ++i)
    {
        float dist = distances.at<float>(j, i);

        float maskVal = (maxFadeRange - dist)/maxFadeRange * 255; // this will scale from 0 (maxFadeRange distance) to 255 (0 distance)
        if (maskVal < 0) maskVal = 0;

        blendingMask.at<unsigned char>(j, i) = maskVal;
    }

    cv::Scalar overlayColor = cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0);

    // color a whole image in overlay colors so that rect and blurred area are coverered by that color
    cv::Mat overlayImage = cv::Mat(size, CV_8UC3, overlayColor);

    // this has created all the stuff that is expensive and can be precomputed for a fixes roi overlay


    float transparency = 0.5f; // 50% transparency





    // now for each image: just do this:

    cv::Mat result = input.clone();


    for (int j = 0; j < blendingMask.rows; ++j)
    for (int i = 0; i < blendingMask.cols; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned char & blendingMaskVal = blendingMask.at<unsigned char>(j, i);

        if (blendingMaskVal) // only blend in areas where blending is necessary
        {
            float alpha = transparency * blendingMaskVal / 255.0f;

            result.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i) = (alpha)*overlayImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i) + (1.0f - alpha)*result.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i);
        }

    }
```

Giving this result with 50% transparency and a fading range of 20 pixels:

[image]

[image]

and this is 20% transparency (variable value = 0.2f) and 100 pixels fading:

[image]

[image]

Comment: use ` CV_DIST_L2` for circular edge regions of the blending mask

Comment: Doing a code cleanup sometimes is not a bad thing, you know. **=,D**